# How can I get node I want from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, .net-2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <Root>
       <Fruits>
            <Fruit>hahahaha</Fruit>
       </Fruits>
  </Root>
```

If I try this code,

```
  string[] cFruitName; int i=0;
  XmlDocument a= new XmlDocument();
  a.LoadXml(getXML());

  foreach (XmlNode xn in a)
  {
     cFruitName[i] = xn.Text;
     i++;
  }
```

but I am getting `null` for `xn.Text`.

All I want is to get values of fruit, like "hahahah" in this example.

**Edit**

I changed my XML now.

Comment: why is there fruit inside Fruit

Comment: is there any better way of doing it, please tell me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(getXML());

var fruits = xml.Descendants("fruit").Select(n => n.Value);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fruits));
```

prints

```
hahahaha
```

use XPath for **.net 2.0** version

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(getXML());

XmlNodeList fruits = xml.SelectNodes("//fruit");

foreach (XmlNode fruit in fruits)
{
    Console.WriteLine (fruit.InnerText);
}
```

prints the same

Comment: sorry I can't use LINQ, I am using .net2.0

Comment: Pro tip: at its heart, each LINQ query is just a shorthand way of saying foreach(thing in collectionOfThings){if(thing.Property == sometest){//do something}}

Comment: Of course you can use Linq . Check here its Linq for .net 2.0 http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] cFruitName; int i=0;
XmlDocument a= new XmlDocument();
a.LoadXml(getXML());

foreach (XmlNode xn in a.Where(x=>x.Text != null))
{
   cFruitName[i] = xn.Text;
   i++;
}
```

or

```
string[] cFruitName; int i=0;
XmlDocument a= new XmlDocument();
a.LoadXml(getXML());

foreach (XmlNode xn in a.Where(x=>x.Name == "fruit"))
{
   cFruitName[i] = xn.Text;
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Check your variable names.

Comment: Ah, I've copied it from the author's post, the previous version.